# Infinite loop with ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, redux, side-effects, ngrx

I'm trying to understand ngrx/effects. I have built a simple function that increments number by 1 with each click. But it's going in an infinite loop when clicked, not sure whats going on. I'm sure im making some stupid mistake.

monitor.effects.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MonitorEffects {
    @Effect()
    compute$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(monitor.ActionTypes.INCREMENT)
        .map((action: monitor.IncrementAction) => action.payload)
        .switchMap(payload => {
            return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
             .map(data => new monitor.IncrementAction(payload+1))
             .catch(err => of(new monitor.InitialAction(0)))
        });

    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private http:Http ) {};
}
```

monitor.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.storeSubsciber = this
      .store
      .select('monitor')
      .subscribe((data: IMonitor.State) => {
        this.value = data.value;
        this.errorMsg = data.error;
        this.currentState = data.currentState;
      });
  }

  increment(value: number) {
    this.store.dispatch(new monitorActions.IncrementAction(value));
  }
```

monitor.reducer.ts

```
export const monitorReducer: ActionReducer<IMonitor.State> = (state = initialState, action: Actions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.INCREMENT:
      return Object.assign({}, { value: action.payload, currentState: ActionTypes.INCREMENT, error: null });
...
...
...

    default:
      return Object.assign({}, { value: 0, currentState: ActionTypes.INITIAL, error: null });
  }
}
```

Comment: if you watch actions `.ofType(monitor.ActionTypes.INCREMENT)` and from your effect you then dispatch an action `monitor.ActionTypes.INCREMENT` (from this part I assume : `monitor.IncrementAction(payload+1)`), then the effect is triggered again, and again, and again, ...

Comment: Yes, thats was the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I made a proper answer in case someone's having a similar problem and don't understand from your example. Glad it's working on your project ! You're welcome :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An `Effect` allows you watch a given action type and react to that action every time it's been dispatched.

So if you watch actions X in some effect and dispatch from that effect another action X, you'll end up in an infinite loop.

In your case : Your action is of type `.ofType(monitor.ActionTypes.INCREMENT)` and from your effect you then dispatch an action `monitor.ActionTypes.INCREMENT` (from this part I assume : `monitor.IncrementAction(payload+1)`), then the effect is triggered again, and again, and again, ...

Comment: For my case, the infinite loop happened because my `.ofType` Action had the same ActionType (first param of `createAction`) as my trigger Action.

Answer (score 12):

I had this same issue, and the answer was that my effect didn't return a completely different action from the one that the current effect was keying on.

For my affect, I only did a `.do()`, and didn't switchMap it to a new action. That was my issue. Because I didn't need to fire a new action, I made a NoopAction that get returns. It is implying that no one should ever use the NoopAction in a reducer.

Comment: I am not sure why not returning a new action caused the endless loop. But returning the NoopAction prevented it.

Comment: If you were not returning a new action, and you were using the `do` (now called `tap` in rxjs 6) operator, you would get an infinite loop, because `do` returns the observable it receives. If you add `dispatch: false` to the Effect declaration like `@Effect({dispatch: false})`, the effect wouldn't return the observable it received.

Comment: @lderrickable you should make that an answer, that's so easy to trip up on.

Answer (score 8):

I was having this issue and the answers here didn't help. For me, I had a "success" action that had a `tap()` to navigate. My browser would lock up and I didn't understand why until I put a log in my tap function and noticed it was getting hit infinitely.

My issue was that the effect was calling itself when `tap` returned the same observable. What I missed, and my solution... was putting `dispatch: false` on my effect to prevent it from dispatching itself.

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
```

Comment: I got almost the same issue as Dallas described. Just used `map()` operator solve the problem for me.

Comment: thank you very much! This solves my problem that I had for hours! Thanks!

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure why this worked... The part I'm unsure about is `My issue was that the effect was calling itself when tap returned the same observable`. Why was the effect calling itself again? I assume this wasn't something you were explicitly doing.

Comment: OK, after reading @Iderrickable's comment in frosty's answer I understand what was happening now.

Comment: see this docs for more context about `dispatch: false` config https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/operators#concatlatestfrom

Answer (score 3):

We already have a correct answer from **Maxime**

I came here for the same issue but nothing worked, in my case it was copy-paste issue

```
export const LoadCustomers = createAction(
    '[Customers] Load Customers' 
)
export const LoadCustomers_Success = createAction(
    '[Customers] Load Customers',
    props<{customers: Array<ICustomer>}>()
)
export const LoadCustomers_Failure = createAction(
    '[Customers] Load Customers',
    props<{error: string}>(),
)
```

My mistake was the type `'[Customers] Load Customers'`, I change the action name but forgot to change the type.